# Getting the Mamp Pro 3.0 to work without the browser automatically appending 8888 to the URL

Tags: wordpress, macos, mamp-pro

I am attempting to change the url to one without using the :8888 suffix.

In the General tab of the MAMP PRO programme, there is a setting which allows Apache and MySQL ports to access other ports which are 80, 443 and 3306. This would seemingly eliminate the need for the :8888 suffix for most users. However when I activate this, I attempt to reach the development site without the :8888 and the browser automatically adds this :8888 suffix which is annoying. I tried clearing the cache but to no avail?

I notice in the WordPress database of the site I am developing, there is a wp-options table with the site url as www.adipurdi.dev:8888 so I changed that to www.adipurdi.dev thinking that may solve the problem. However it doesn't look like that has changed anything.

I tried a number of things like starting and stopping the MAC OSX apache server and I am stuck on this problem. If anyone has any thoughts then please let me know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using WordPress there should be 2 URLS in the database you have to change, there's a "siteurl" column and a "home" column that both need to be without the :8888 after you changed your settings in MAMP.

Comment: Synchronicity at work!

I just discovered that by adjusting the two urls in the settings page of WordPress I could achieve this.

Many thanks